# Ramda - Transform array by multiple groupings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I am trying to accomplish the following using `ramda`:

Here's a sample of what the `array` will look like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "ON",
    type: "TYPE_1"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "OFF",
    type: "TYPE_1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "ON",
    type: "TYPE_1"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    value: "OFF",
    type: "TYPE_2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "OFF",
    type: "TYPE_2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "OFF",
    type: "TYPE_2"
  }
]
```

Here's how I want it to look:

```
[
 {
  name: "TYPE_1"
  enabled: 2,
  disabled: 0,
 },
 {
  name: "TYPE_2",
  enabled: 0,
  disabled: 1
 }
]
```

Basically I need to group by `type` and `id` where their combination could be repeated but only account for one.

Here's what I've already attempted:

```
pipe(
  groupBy(prop('type')),
  map(applySpec({
    name: pipe(head, prop('type')),
    enabled: reduce((acc, item) => item.value === "ON" ? add(acc, 1) : acc, 0),
    disabled: reduce((acc, item) => item.value === "OFF" ? add(acc, 1) : acc, 0) 
  })),
  values,
)(list)
```

But it does not work as this returns the following:

```
[
 {
  name: "TYPE_1",
  enabled: 2,
  disabled: 1
 },
 {
  type: "TYPE_2",
  enabled: 0,
  disabled: 3
]
```

The missing piece would be to only account for each `id` of each `type`.

Comment: Please explain the grouping logic, and add a code sample of what you tried to do.

Comment: @OriDrori updated, lmk if that helps. thanks!

Comment: What does this sentence "Basically I need to group by type and id where their combination could be repeated but only account for one." mean?

Comment: @OriDrori that only one `id/type` pair should be accounted for. so if there's many objects with the same `id` and `type` combination, only count it as `enabled` or `disabled` once. not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: So `TYPE_1` would only account for `id: 1` - enabled 1, disabled 1. Ignore `id: 2`. TYPE_3 should be enabled: 0, and disabled: 3?

Comment: @OriDrori so each `id` should only be counted once. even if `id:1` is repeated multiple times, it will only be accounted as either `enabled/disabled`

Comment: @MustKillBill - figured that out. See my solution.

Comment: @OriDrori beautiful, sorry for the confusion. thanks a million

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I'm still confused by the requirements.  It's not a problem that if the first two elements in your input were switched, we'd change from `{"name":"TYPE_1","enabled":2,"disabled":0}` to `{"name":"TYPE_1","enabled":1,"disabled":1}`? That seems odd to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group again by the `id`, take the head from each subgroup, flatten, and then apply the spec:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, values, map, applySpec, head, ifElse, any, always, filter, propEq, length } = R

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('type')),
  values,
  map(pipe(
    groupBy(prop('id')),
    values,
    map(applySpec({
      name: pipe(head, prop('type')),
      value: ifElse(any(propEq('value', 'ON')), always('ON'), always('OFF')),
    })),
    applySpec({
      name: pipe(head, prop('name')),
      enabled: pipe(filter(propEq('value', 'ON')), length),
      disabled: pipe(filter(propEq('value', 'OFF')), length),
    })
  )),
)

const arr = [{"id":1,"value":"ON","type":"TYPE_1"},{"id":1,"value":"OFF","type":"TYPE_1"},{"id":2,"value":"ON","type":"TYPE_1"},{"id":3,"value":"OFF","type":"TYPE_2"},{"id":3,"value":"OFF","type":"TYPE_2"},{"id":3,"value":"OFF","type":"TYPE_2"}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't see that the `flatten` calls add anything.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope. Leftovers from a previous solution.

Comment: Any suggestion for a function name for Ramda to add `const whatDoWeCallIt = (fn) => pipe(groupBy(fn), values)`.  This is far too common a pattern.

Comment: Lol. I actually though about it before, but this should be the signature `const fn = curry((fn, arr) => pipe(groupBy(fn), values)(arr))`. Regarding the name, something like `flatGroupBy`. I'm not a great namer.

Comment: Yes, of course we'd actually do the Ramda magic currying.  Perhaps `groupTogetherBy`?

Comment: @OriDrori hey Ori, so I've been playing with your solution and it appears that it only determines the `enabled/disabled` value based on the value on the first object in the array

Comment: @OriDrori thinking the problem might be in the `map(head)`

Comment: Found a better solution. Apply spec on the group, and check use any to check if there's any least one 'ON'.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - the together seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const transform = applySpec({
  name: head,
  enabled: pipe(last, filter(propEq('value', 'ON')), length),
  disabled: pipe(last, filter(propEq('value', 'OFF')), length),
})
const fn = pipe(groupBy(prop('type')), toPairs, map(transform))
```

[demo](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%7B%0A%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20value%3A%20%22ON%22%2C%0A%20%20type%3A%20%22TYPE_1%22%0A%20%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%0A%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20value%3A%20%22OFF%22%2C%0A%20%20type%3A%20%22TYPE_1%22%0A%20%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%0A%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20value%3A%20%22ON%22%2C%0A%20%20type%3A%20%22TYPE_1%22%0A%20%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%0A%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20value%3A%20%22OFF%22%2C%0A%20%20type%3A%20%22TYPE_2%22%0A%20%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%0A%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20value%3A%20%22OFF%22%2C%0A%20%20type%3A%20%22TYPE_2%22%2C%0A%20%7D%2C%0A%20%7B%0A%20%20id%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20value%3A%20%22OFF%22%2C%0A%20%20type%3A%20%22TYPE_2%22%0A%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20transform%20%3D%20applySpec%28%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20head%2C%0A%20%20enabled%3A%20pipe%28last%2C%20filter%28propEq%28%27value%27%2C%20%27ON%27%29%29%2C%20length%29%2C%0A%20%20disabled%3A%20pipe%28last%2C%20filter%28propEq%28%27value%27%2C%20%27OFF%27%29%29%2C%20length%29%2C%0A%7D%29%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20pipe%28groupBy%28prop%28%27type%27%29%29%2C%20toPairs%2C%20map%28transform%29%29%0A%0Afn%28input%29%0A%0A)

Comment: thanks man, but this returns `[{"disabled": 1, "enabled": 2, "name": "TYPE_1"}, {"disabled": 3, "enabled": 0, "name": "TYPE_2"}]` but what I expect is `[{"disabled": 0, "enabled": 2, "name": "TYPE_1"}, {"disabled": 1, "enabled": 0, "name": "TYPE_2"}]`. I need to count each `id` only once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, somwhat different from the one by OriDrori.  It matches the given case, but I'm still not certain about the general rules, so it's possible that this doesn't actually capture the requirements properly.

```js
const extract = pipe (
  groupBy (toString),              // {JSON_key1: [{id, value, type}, {id, value, type}, ...] JSON_key2: [{id, value, type}, ...], ...}
  map (head),                      // {JSON_key1: {id, value, type}, JSON_key2: {id, value, type}, ...}
  values,                          // [{id, value, type}, {id, value, type}, ...]
  groupBy (prop ('type')),         // {TYPE_1: [{id, value, type}, {id, value, type}, ...], "TYPE_2":[{id, value, type}]}
  map (countBy (prop ('value'))),  // {TYPE_1: {ON: 2, OFF: 1}, TYPE_2: {OFF: 1}}
  toPairs,                         // [[TYPE_1, {ON: 2, OFF: 1}], [TYPE_2, {OFF: 1}]]
  map (applySpec ({
    type: nth(0), 
    enabled: pathOr(0, [1, 'ON']), 
    disabled: pathOr(0, [1, 'OFF'])
  }))                              // [{type: "TYPE_1", enabled: 2, disabled: 1}, {type: "TYPE_2", enabled: 0, disabled: 1}]
) 

const data = [{id: 1, value: "ON", type: "TYPE_1"}, {id: 1, value: "OFF", type: "TYPE_1"}, {id: 2, value: "ON", type: "TYPE_1"}, {id: 3, value: "OFF", type: "TYPE_2"}, {id: 3, value: "OFF", type: "TYPE_2"}, {id: 3, value: "OFF", type: "TYPE_2"}];

console .log (extract (data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, toString, map, head, values, prop, countBy, 
                toPairs, applySpec, nth, pathOr} = R </script>
```

Ramda's `toString` is not particularly fast.  If you preferred, you could replace the first line of the pipeline with something like this:

```js
  groupBy (({id, value, type}) => `${id}|${value}|${type}`),
```

Also, the `map(applySpec)` lines feel a bit complex.  We could replace them with something like this:

```js
  map (([type, {OFF: disabled = 0, ON: enabled = 0}]) => ({type, enabled, disabled}))
```

Note the style of a pipeline of small, relatively simple individual transformations.  This to me is Ramda's sweet spot.  Ramda is designed to support many different styles of functional programming, but this style is most central.